# Errors in function calls but a very weird exception case

Tags: python, function

The specific function doesn't matter, but here's one for context:

```
def func(x, y):
    if x <= y:
        return x, y
```

Using this function, I ran the four cases below.
I expectedly ran into errors except for the first case, of which, I have no idea why it works.
Could someone explain the logic behind python's function call. Why does the first case work?

This (case 1) came from an exam with most people picking ERROR. However, the correct answer was NONE.

**CASE 1**
`func(y, y=x)`

```
None
```

**CASE 2**
`func(x=y,x)`

```
  Cell In[18], line 1
    func(x=y,x)
              
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

**CASE 3**
`func(x,x=y)`

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 1
----> 1 func(x,x=y)

TypeError: func() got multiple values for argument 'x'
```

**CASE 4**
`func(y=1,y=x)`

```
  Cell In[19], line 1
    func(y=1,y=x)
             
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated: y
```

Comment: None of those errors are weird. Not only that, but they explain the specific problem in each case. Have you read the error messages and tried searching for them?

Answer (score 2):

The thing you might be getting tripped up on is that `x` and `y` are different sets of variables within the function vs the caller.  The fact that you're reusing the names AND not using them consistently makes the code unnecessarily confusing, which in turn makes it harder to interpret the errors.

Taking case 1 as an example, with some actual values added for the variables:

```
x = 1
y = 2
func(y, y=x)
```

`func` is being called with `2` as the `x` argument and `1` as the `y` argument, NOT the other way around.  The names of the variables in the outer scope have no impact on how they're passed as arguments.

It's exactly as if you'd done:

```
a = 1
b = 2
func(b, y=a)
```

which is of course perfectly valid, and it's easier to see in this version that `b` is `x` and `a` is `y`.

In your other examples you get an error because it's ambiguous which argument is which; the fact that you're using the names `x` and `y` in the outer scope does nothing to resolve the ambiguity in the error cases, but neither does it create ambiguity in the first case (at least as far as Python is concerned -- for a human reader it's obviously confusing, which was probably the point of the test question).